# How to transform a tabular data into transactions in spark(scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an order transaction dataset, which looks like the following table

```
1,John,iPhone Cover,9.99
2,Jack,iPhone Cover,9.99 
4,Jill,Samsung Galaxy Cover,9.95
3,John,Headphones,5.49
5,Bob,iPad Cover,5.45
```

I am considering grouping data within certain differences into different transactions. For example, I would group product 1,2,4 into transaction list List(1,2,4) for their absolute differences in price is less than 1. And on the other hand, to put product 3, 5 into same transactions List(3,5).

I know I can exactly do so in Python with following code:

```
f = open('test.csv', 'r')
current_price = 0
res = []
ary = []
for id, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    dt = line.strip().split(',')
    if id ==0:
        current_price = float(dt[3])
    if abs(float(dt[3]) - current_price) < 1:
        ary.append(dt[0])
    else:
        res.append(ary)
        current_price = float(dt[3])
        ary = [dt[0]]
res.append(ary)
print res
```

But as scala is functional programming language, how to achieve same goal  with functional programming style?

Comment: Do you really need to do this in Spark? Since you're doing something that requires a linear scan (since you're grouping based on the difference from the previous item) you get no benefit from the parallization.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I am just wondering how scala solve this kind of sequential scanning issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
val xs = input.map(_.split(",")) 
//List(Array(1, John, iPhone Cover, 9.99),
//     Array(2, Jack, iPhone Cover, 9.99),
//     Array(4, Jill, Samsung Galaxy Cover, 9.95),
//     Array(3, John, Headphones, 5.49),
//     Array(5, Bob, iPad Cover, 5.45))

xs.tail.foldLeft((xs.head(3), List(List(xs.head(0))))) {
  case ((cur, acc), e) =>
    if (Math.abs(cur.toDouble - e(3).toDouble) < 1.0)
      (cur, (acc.head :+ e(0)) :: acc.tail)
    else (e(3), List(e(0)) :: acc)
}._2.reverse
//List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 5))
```

We pass into each iteration the current price of the current group, and the list of groups so far. If the current price is close enough to the next price, we add the id to the current group. Otherwise, we start a new group from the next element, and change the current price to the price from that.

Looks more complex than it really is. If I was doing this for real, I'd do something like the below - define a case class to hold the values of each line, and a method for "close enough price".

```
case class Line(id: Int, person: String, product: String, price: Double) {
    def closeEnough(other: Line) = (Math.abs(price - other.price) < 1.0)
  }
```

Then make objects from the lines

```
val xs = input.map { l => val xs = l.split(","); Line(xs(0).toInt, xs(1), xs(2), xs(3).toDouble) }
// List(Line(1,John,iPhone Cover,9.99),
//      Line(2,Jack,iPhone Cover,9.99),
//      Line(4,Jill,Samsung Galaxy Cover,9.95),
//      Line(3,John,Headphones,5.49),
//      Line(5,Bob,iPad Cover,5.45))
```

Now do the fold, but work with Lines

```
val groups = xs.tail.foldLeft(List(List(xs.head))) {
  case (acc, e) =>
    if (e.closeEnough(acc.head.head))
      (acc.head :+ e) :: acc.tail
    else List(e) :: acc
}.reverse
```

And if you need to, convert to lists of lists of IDs

```
groups.map(_.map(_.id))
// List(List(1, 2, 4), List(3, 5))
```